# How to change the brightness of an image as its Ratingbar's rating is changed?

Tags: android, image, android-fragments, brightness, ratingbar

I am Android novice, hoping my question is clear enough. I have an image and a rating bar at a certain position in an adapter and I add them to a Fragment. I would like the brightness of the image to change as the user changes the ratings on the Ratingbar but have no clue where to begin. 
This is the function where I instantiate the layout that contains them :

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)container.getContext().getSystemService
(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rmd1_custom_imageslider_layout, null);   

ImageView image=(ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.myimage);             
image.setImageResource(CriteriaImages.get(position));

TextView text=(TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.myImageViewText);             
text.setText("Rate my "+CriteriaNames.get(position)+" today");

RatingBar rating = (RatingBar) layout.findViewById(R.id.ratingCategory);
rating.setId(position);

Button btn=(Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
((ViewPager) container).addView(layout);
return layout; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a listener, a RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener.

```
rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onRatingBarChanged( .... ) {

        //DO YOUR STUFF, like setting the alpha value of your image.

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you also happen to know how to dynamically change the brightness of the image?

Comment: You can set the alpha value, either for the imageView or for the drawable, if that's what you mean with brightness. Setting it on the drawable is probably best, so you can set a background to the imageView. Set a white background to fade it to white, a black background to fade it to black. imageView.getDrawable().setAlpha(0-255); That should work :)